# Get latest record for customers by Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the latest phone number of customer by date. There are multiple entries for the same customer. But out of that I only want the record which has the maximum date.

Sample Data,

```
|cust_id |  phone   |    hist_date
|  A     |  1234    |    2015-10-02
|  A     |  4567    |    2016-10-02
|  A     |  7896    |    2017-10-02
|  B     |  6456    |    2015-10-02
|  B     |  8621    |    2016-10-02
|  B     |  6382    |    2017-10-02
|  A     |  1393    |    2018-10-02
```

Desired result is

```
|cust_id |  phone   |    hist_date
|  A     |  1393    |    2018-10-02
|  B     |  6382    |    2017-10-02
```

Please don't hard-code it with year. I need it to be dynamic so that every time only the latest date record will show. I know this can be achieved by Sub-query and CTE using ROW NUMBER. I tried but haven't got it right. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: What were wrong with the (very likely) suggested duplicates that you were shown when writing this question? This is a very common qusetion on SO, and there are lots of duplicate questions with answers (or links to said duplicates). What attempts did you make and why didn't they work?

Comment: I tried using CTE but I was not able to make it dynamic. I hard coded it with the latest year. I saw the suggested questions but I didn't understand those queries that's why I asked seperately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `row_number()` analytic function

```
select * from 
(select *,row_number()over(partition by cust_id order by hist_date desc) rn
from logic
) t where t.rn=1
```

or you can use corelate subquery

```
 select t1.* from logic t1
 where t1.hist_date=( select max(hist_date) 
                     from logic t2 where  t1.cust_id=t2.cust_id
                     )
```

Comment: Without goup by can we use cust_id in where with aggregate function. Please check.

Comment: @SurajKumar yes we can

Comment: My Table Name is logic. but I'm getting Syntax error when trying row_number()

Comment: @UtkarshSharma sql server suppoer row_number() so it can't be like that plz show us error

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfect.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin  I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Got it.

Answer (score 1):

use `row_number()` window function

```
select * from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by cus_id order by hist_date desc) as rn
from logic
)A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following query.

```
create table temp(cust_id char(1),  phone char(5),  hist_date date)
insert into temp values
('A', '1234', '2015-10-02'),
('A', '4567', '2016-10-02'),
('A', '7896', '2017-10-02'),
('B', '6456', '2015-10-02'),
('B', '8621', '2016-10-02'),
('B', '6382', '2017-10-02'),
('A', '1393', '2018-10-02')
```

Now the actual query.

```
Select a.* from temp a
inner join (
Select cust_id, MAX(hist_date) as hist_date from temp
group by cust_id
)b on a.cust_id = b.cust_id and a.hist_date = b.hist_date
```

[**Live Demo**](https://rextester.com/WGHM95516)